# Simulink signal for array message passing

Tags: matlab, simulink, ros

I want to publish a 2-dimensional array from a MATLAB function in Simulink to a ROS topic.

I have followed [this tutorial](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/robotics/examples/get-started-with-ros-in-simulink.html) where an example is given for a [`geometry_msgs/Point`](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Point.html). However, I want to use [`std_msgs/Float32MultiArray`](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Float32MultiArray.html) which is a bit more complex:

[image: screenshot]

I cannot even make it compile with `Data` and `DataOffset` only:

[image]

I get the following error:

> Error in port widths or dimensions. Output port 1 of '.../MATLAB Function' is a [1x10] matrix.
>
> Error in port widths or dimensions. Input port 2 of '.../Bus Assignment' is a one dimensional vector with 128 elements.

Comment: You need to make the signal sizes match. The "fcn" block should produce 128x1 to match the Data in Bus signal.

Comment: What? That makes no sense... What if I want to send more than 128 elements? I want to be able to publish a 2-dimensional array, both with variable number of rows and columns.